# Changing font mid edit within a cell

Tags: vba, excel, fonts

I would like to change the font size of a portion of the text within a cell.  For example in the cell I type John Smith in the default font size then run the macro and reduce the font so the following text is 10 point.

John Smith (12 point)- (run macro) ABC Company (10 point)

I can only get the macro to change the font of the entire cell and only before I start typing in the cell.

Comment: You can use the `.Character()` object to denote each character's property, but as @Rory pointed out only after the cell has been edited.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The code won't run while you're editing the cell. You can use the Font size dropdown though.

Comment: Why do you want to run the macro *while* editing the cell? I can't really think of a reason that'd be necessary. The macro would work just as well if you run it after you enter the data, no?

Answer (score 0):

1. In a default 12pt font, start typing:
              **J·o·h·n**·*<space>*·**S·m·i·t·h**·*<space>*
2. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd> again.
3. Continue typing:
              *<hyphen><space>*-A·B·C·*<space>*·**C·o·m·p·a·n·y**
4. Hit <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Results:

[image: reduce_font]

If you do this a lot, you might want to take the time to assign the Decrease Font Size command to the QAT. More on the QAT at: [Customize the Quick Access Toolbar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA010362102.aspx).